# Salesforce1 vs. desktop view page

Tags: salesforce1-platform

I have the view action overridden for a custom object. But in Salesforce1, I want to use the standard view action. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you uncheck the "mobile ready" flag on your page, Salesforce1 will only use the standard view, not the page override.

Comment: That works for my lightening page. But it's using the standard view in the browser too on the phone. I thought the phone browser should be same as desktop browser.